# what's the difference between these Intents?

Tags: android

I understand the concept of the intent, but I don't understand the difference between

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH)
Intent shopIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format(str)));

// To open directly into youtube app
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
```

can someone simplify the difference between action web search and action view?
and the difference between the last two action view?

I'm trying to learn programming for android apps.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[ACTION_WEB_SEARCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH) has 2 distinct working patterns - if you pass in url that starts with http(s), then that web page is opened. If instead of url, you pass in a word or phrase - then google search is opened

[ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) can be used to display many different objects - I guess if you pass in http(s) url into it, then it will again open up a browser - so in this specific usecase it seems similar to ACTION_WEB_SEARCH. The difference is that ACTION_VIEW can be used on other objects (mailto: will open up a e-mail compose window, tel: will open up a dialer, etc)

The last one is again more specific - opens a specific Youtube video. I recommend going through the linked page in official Android docs to learn all the nuances.

Answer (score 1):

You should better go through https://developer.android.com first, there you can find the answers easily.

`ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` is used to **perform a web search**. See [this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH)

While `ACTION_VIEW` is used to **display the data to the user**. See [this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)

and the difference between last two `intents` is that first is taking a `formatted string` as its argument whereas second is taking the `string` directly.